# Eclipse Compiler Error (can not be resolved to a type)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with my eclipse, all class `can not be resolved to a type` when creating new workspace all errors are disappeared, but after a clean or updating maven, I got the same problem.

[image: ec]

Comment: 1. Please don't post images of code and/or error messages, copy the text instead. 2. You need to show us your code. 3. where do you expect those types to be taken from, what build system do you use?

Answer (score -1):

First, check import. Then, check libraries (dependencies), classpath,...